# whats the difference between word-break: normal; and word-break: keep:all;?

Tags: css, word-break

These seem to do the same thing, whats the difference?
https://jsfiddle.net/pmuub8w1/2/

```
    p{
          word-break:normal;
   }

   p{
         word-break: keep-all;
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break *"**keep-all**
    Don't allow word breaks for CJK text.  Non-CJK text behavior is the same as for normal."*  (CJK = Chinese Japanese Korean) And an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmuub8w1/3/)

Comment: Please read the relevant documentation before asking, as @Kaiido quoted, all the available values for the property are explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **normal:** Follow normal line break rules, that is to break line at the space between words. So even if the last words goes out of bounds of the container, sentence won't go to next line till next word comes. This will be done for all text even for [CJK characters](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjx1sLs49fUAhVC7YMKHejlCIwQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCJK_characters&usg=AFQjCNGNY4t4CuknACIiA7I1avIM6DMA1A) (Chinese, Japanese, Korean and derivatives)
2. **break-all:** Break at the characters if out of bounds, that means a word itself will be broken and taken to the second line. So suppose `ALongWord` is going out of bounds at the `AL` then `break-all` will make the rest `ongWord` go to the second line. This will not be done for the `CJK` characters.
3. **keep-all:** Break by normal line rules except for the CJK characters. It's like `normal` except in case of `CJK` it won't break at all (neither by line rules as done by `normal` nor at characters as done by `break-all`)

Following is the screenshot of the example at [Mozzila documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break).
[image: word-break]

Notice the difference between how the non CJK and CJK sentences are treated.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the purpose of regurgitating existing documentation.

Comment: It was regurgitated with some extra words to explain the documentation as that wasn't clear enough.

Comment: THANKS 11thdimesnion that helped a lot, straight forward and simple, I wouldnt have known what cjk was

Comment: Note the reason this exists is that CJK are typically written without spaces. In that case `normal`'s behavior is an acceptable default, but sometimes not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer gets the important part right: `normal` and `keep-all` are the same for non-CJK text. However, the description of how CJK text behaves is wrong.

In `normal`, CJK can have a line broken **anywhere**. This is because CJK is usually used without spaces and breaking anywhere is acceptable (if not perfect). In the screenshot, `本当` is one word but it's split in half at the start of the last line.

In `break-all`, non-CJK text can be broken anywhere, the same as CJK text in `normal`.

In `keep-all`, CJK text works the same as text in other scripts works in `normal` - that is, if there is a long line without any whitespace, it can  overflow the container. If you want CJK text to wrap you must manually insert whitespace. This can be useful when combined with zero-width spaces to create line breaks at natural word boundaries. In the screenshot, because the Japanese text has no spaces, it's treated the same as the long word in English and overflows the container.